# Replace generated Details view with a viewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to simply replace the generated Details method with a viewModel in a controller.
I know it should be simple, but I am getting an error when adding the .Find(id) action. I'm guessing it is a syntax thing, or the Find action doesnt works for viewModels, but cant find the answer anywere. Any help is much appreciated.

So trying to go from this:

```
   public ViewResult Details(int id)
    {
        Artist artist = db.Artists.Find(id);
        return View(artist);
    }
```

To this

```
public ViewResult Details(int id)
    {

        var viewModel = new ArtistsDetailsVM();
        viewModel.Artists = db.Artists.Find(id);
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

Edit: to include viewModel:

```
public class ArtistsDetailsVM
{
    public IEnumerable<Artist> Artists { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Album> Albums { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Song> Songs { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ViewModels are usually used when you want to composite a bunch of data from multiple models, collections, lookup lists, etc, into a strongly typed ViewModel object that you can reference in the View.

So if you want to use a ViewModel here you have two options; you can either use an automapper (which is overkill here), or you can make sure your "Artists" property on your ArtistsDefailtsVM matches the type returned by db.Artists.Find().

Can you post the code for  ArtistsDefailtsVM, and the error your're getting? It seems like .Find(id) returns a single Artist, but your VM's "Artists" property name implies a collection. That might be the source of your error.

Comment: Thanks for the response - I'm going to be using the viewModel to bring in some additional data, but wanted to get it working as a direct replacement in the first instance. I have edited the question to include the viewModel - and from what you have said I think the error exists due to using IEnumerable for the artists where as the .find only works with a single artist.

Comment: Yup - removing the IEnumerable from artists in the viewModel worked - thanks for your help.